# Java 8 Comparator chaining with a reverse on single property

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I am using a `Comparator` to sort a list of `Student` objects.

I want to reverse the sorting on the `id` property, but using `reverse()` method applies it on the whole sorting.

How to make it happens only on the `id`?

Here's my code so far:

```
 public List<Student> getStudents(List<String> events) {
    Comparator<Student> comparatorStudents = Comparator.comparing(Student::getCGPA).thenComparing(Student::getName)
      .thenComparingInt(Student::getID).reverse();
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    //Filling students
    Collections.sort(students, comparatorStudents);
    return students;
  }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Change the last bit to:

```
.thenComparing(Student::getID, Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Or, if you want to avoid autoboxing:

```
.thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getID).reversed())
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "to avoid autoboxing"

Comment: @MartinDinev The first variation accepts a `Function<Student, Integer>`, which means it's converting the `int` returned by `Student.getID()` to an `Integer`. `Comparator.comparingInt()`, on the other hand, accepts a `ToIntFunction`, and it does the comparison using just the primitive.

Answer (score 5):

Put the call of [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) inside `thenComparing`:

```
public List<Student> getStudents(List<String> events) {
    Comparator<Student> comparatorStudents = Comparator.comparing(Student::getCGPA)
       .thenComparing(Student::getName)
       .thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getID).reversed());
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    //Filling students
    Collections.sort(students, comparatorStudents);
    return students;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Guava's `Ordering` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) for almost all of my sorting. It's very well documented here: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained.

Among other things, I like `Ordering` because:

1. it uses a "fluent" API.
2. Orderings implement Comparable and can therefore be used anywhere you can use a Comparable.
3. they are naturally thread safe (which means you can declare them as static constants and reuse a single instance everywhere).

In your case, I'd write the code as follows:

```
private static final Ordering<Student> BY_GPA = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Student::getCGPA);
private static final Ordering<Student> BY_NAME = Ordering.nautural().onResultOf(Student::getName);
private static final Ordering<Student> BY_ID_DESCENDING = Ordering.natural().reverse().onResultOf(Student::getID);

// I spent approximately zero time coming up with a good name for this constant
public static final Ordering<Student> STUDENT_ORDER = BY_CPA.compound(BY_NAME).compound(BY_ID_DESCENDING);

public List<Student> getStudents(List<String> events) {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    //Filling students
    Collections.sort(students, STUDENT_ORDER);
    return students;
}
```

Personally, I would normally declare those constants on the Student class, such that anyone interacting with `Student` objects anywhere can readily find and reuse what they need to sort them. In that scenario, I'd probably name the public constant `DEFAULT_ORDER` or something to that effect, but without more context I'm not sure if sorting by GPA is the default you really want.

You absolutely don't have to declare four separate constants -- the three private ones can absolutely be declared inline. I like to do it that way because I find that it improves readability.

Also: I'm not sure what your needs are with regard to duplication, but if Students are guaranteed to be unique and you have a good implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`, I'd encourage you to use `Set<Student> students = new TreeSet<Student>();`. That way, they get sorted as you add to the collection, and they stay that way automatically if you modify the collection.

Comment: I'll add that I've been doing it this way since Java 6, and had not properly educated myself on what's new in Java 8 with respect to Comparators (it looks like it took a lot of influence from Guava!). I defer to the other answers, which appeared while I was writing mine. :)

Comment: Very interesting way to do things.